# i want my application to be access by more than one user at the same time SQL database

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have developed an desktop application in `C#` and `sql server 2008`.
Now I want my application to be accessed by more than one user at the same time.

The idea is a database should be on 1 PC (server) and application will be installed on other PCs (clients) all connected in a LAN.  I want all user from different PCs (clients) can access the DB (on SERVER) and perform CRUD operations.

My conn, cnf file has connection string:

```
server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Database1med;Trusted_Connection=Yes;\
```

I dont know steps to do this. please help to achieve the idea in implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.linglom.com/it-support/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/ this is the answer you can check this out

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you authentication mode to be SQL Server Authentication ([Read More Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284(v=sql.105).aspx))

Then you need to change your connection string to be like this:

```
server=192.168.1.1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Database1med;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

Assuming `192.168.1.1` is the IP address of the Server you mentioned.

For that purpose, you mean need to either activate the sa user (Not a good idea for let you users access using sa) or create a new login ([Read More here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562(v=sql.105).aspx))

For Network access configuration: [Read this](http://www.linglom.com/it-support/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/).

You need to either disable firewall (for testing purposes only - not recommended). or `Create Rules` using `Control Panel => Firewall => Allow a program through Windows Firewall`:

- Create an inbound rule for port TCP 1433 - allow the connection
- Create an outbound rule for port TCP 1433 - allow the connection

Don't forget to restart the SQL-Server instance from the configuration manager after doing all of this.

Comment: but it shows an error <A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)>

Comment: @jijo Network access configuration is not a piece of cake because it has security side effects. You need to configure your firewall in order for SQL port to be accessible by other machines: Read this : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165718(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I enabled TCP/IP and also configure windows firewall but again got the same error

Comment: I enabled TCP/IP and also configure windows firewall but again got the same error

Comment: ,@currarpickt Is there any other method to access sql server 2008 from another computer,

Comment: @jijo http://www.linglom.com/it-support/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/

Comment: http://www.linglom.com/it-support/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/ @user3185569 this is the answer